# Update VSO history and add attachments

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-sdk

How do I add history records and attachments to a workitem in VSO 2015?
So far I have succeeded in logging in, running a query and retrieve the workitems from the query result.
But the workitem objects doesn't have properties for history or attatchments:

```
WorkItemTrackingHttpClient witClient = new WorkItemTrackingHttpClient(new Uri(collectionUri), new VssAadCredential("first.last@blablabla.com", "secret"));
List<QueryHierarchyItem> items = witClient.GetQueriesAsync(teamProjectName, QueryExpand.All,2).Result;

QueryHierarchyItem myQueriesFolder = items.FirstOrDefault(qhi => qhi.Name.Equals("Shared Queries"));
if (myQueriesFolder != null)
{
    string queryName = "All Workitems";
    QueryHierarchyItem newBugsQuery = null;
    if (myQueriesFolder.Children != null)
    {
        newBugsQuery = myQueriesFolder.Children.FirstOrDefault(qhi => qhi.Name.Equals(queryName));
    }

    WorkItemQueryResult result = witClient.QueryByIdAsync(newBugsQuery.Id).Result;

    if (result.WorkItemRelations.Count() > 0)
    {
        int skip = 0;
        const int batchSize = 100;
        IEnumerable<WorkItemLink> workItemRefs;
        do
        {
            workItemRefs = result.WorkItemRelations.Skip(skip).Take(batchSize);
            if (workItemRefs.Count() > 0)
            {
                // get details for each work item in the batch
                List<WorkItem> workItems = witClient.GetWorkItemsAsync(workItemRefs.Select(wir => wir.Target.Id)).Result;
                foreach (WorkItem workItem in workItems)
                {
                    // write work item to console
                    if ((string)workItem.Fields["System.WorkItemType"] == "Requirement")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", workItem.Id, workItem.Fields["System.Title"]);

                        //workItem doesn't have properties for history or attachmens...
                        WorkItemHistory history = (WorkItemHistory) workItem.Fields["System.History"];
                    }
                }
            }
            skip += batchSize;
        }
        while (workItemRefs.Count() == batchSize);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to retrieve the history you need to loop through the revisions of a work item (WorkItem.Revisions) and output the history field for each revision.

You can't use WorkItem.Revision and instead should use WorkItem.Fields["System.History"].value to retrieve it.

Attachments are in WorkItem.Attachments for both read and write.

Answer (score 0):

Using namespace:

- Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client
- Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking

Refer to following code for details:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client;

namespace TFSAPI
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string project = "https://xxxxxxxx.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection";
            NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential("username","pwd");
            BasicAuthCredential cred = new BasicAuthCredential(nc);
            TfsClientCredentials tc = new TfsClientCredentials(cred);
            tc.AllowInteractive = false;
            TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(project), tc);
            WorkItemStore workItemStore = tpc.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
            Project teamProject = workItemStore.Projects["Sonar"];
            WorkItemType workItemType = teamProject.WorkItemTypes["User Story"];
            int workitemid = 2;
            WorkItem wi = workItemStore.GetWorkItem(workitemid);
            //Update history
            wi.Fields["History"].Value = "You comments";
            //Add attachment
            wi.Attachments.Add(new Attachment("E:\\a\\1.txt"));
            wi.Save();
        }
    }
}
```